# Change UISlider track color for multiple colors in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Can I use the value I obtain(sender.value) to change the color as the slider moves? I am trying to change the color from green to yellow to red as the slider moves. Please help in swift thanks!

```
let brokeSlider = UISlider(frame:CGRectMake(5, 440, 355, 20))
            brokeSlider.minimumValue = 0
            brokeSlider.maximumValue = 1
            brokeSlider.continuous = true
            brokeSlider.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            brokeSlider.value = 0
            brokeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AnnotationPhotoWidget.sliderValueDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
            self.view.addSubview(brokeSlider)

    func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider) {
            print("value--\(sender.value)")
    }
```

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: did seem to work :( @AshishVerma

Comment: Does the print work?

Comment: @FredLoh yeah the print works

Comment: Are the minimumValue to addSubview lines inside viewdidload?

Comment: @FredLoh No it is not

Comment: Check out the sample class I posted, if its not inside viewDidLoad I'm not really sure where you're defining it.

Comment: This can be achieved by checking the 2nd part of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575844/4833705. You can make the track colors of the slider clear, put the class from the answer behind/underneath it, then animate using the caLayer colors of your choice as it progresses

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider) {
     print("value--\(sender.value)")
     if sender.value <= 0.3 {
        brokeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.green
     } else if sender.value > 0.3 && sender.value <= 0.6 {
           brokeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.yellow
     } else {
          brokeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.red
     }
}
```

Comment: No, Thanks for trying! I have also tried to do if brokeSlider.value = 0.3 {} / but I can't seem to get it working! @AshishVerma

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AnnotationPhotoWidget: UIViewController  {
    let brokeSlider = UISlider(frame:CGRectMake(5, 440, 355, 20))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        brokeSlider.minimumValue = 0
        brokeSlider.maximumValue = 1
        brokeSlider.continuous = true
        brokeSlider.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        brokeSlider.value = 0
        brokeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AnnotationPhotoWidget.sliderValueDidChange(_:)),forControlEvents: .
            ValueChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(brokeSlider)
    }

    func sliderValueDidChange(sender: UISlider) {
        if sender.value <= 0.3 {
            brokeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        } else if sender.value > 0.3 && sender.value <= 0.6 {
            brokeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        } else {
            brokeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think my answer was same as yours?

Comment: @AshishVerma it is, only difference would be the viewDidLoad

Comment: @AshishVerma It worked when I used apples UIslider in the story board, it didn't work when I created my own sliders as pictured above ^^^^, Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @FredLoh Read Comment above, Thanks for the help!

Comment: But this wont change the value dynamically

Answer (score 2):

@ashimVerma's solution works great. To take it up a notch and get smooth color transitions, give this a whirl:

[image]

```
@objc func sliderValueDidChange(sender: UISlider) {
    let saturation = 0.9 // 0...1
    let lightness = 0.46 // 0...1

    let sliderPercentage = sender.value / sender.maximumValue
    let invertedPercentage = 1 - sliderPercentage
    let hue = CGFloat(invertedPercentage * 120 / 360)

    let brightness = lightness + saturation * min(lightness, 1 - lightness)

    var adjustedSaturation: CGFloat = 0.0
    if brightness > 0 {
        adjustedSaturation = 2 * (1 - lightness / brightness)
    }

    let trackColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: adjustedSaturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1)
    brokeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = trackColor
}
```

This works by utilizing the HSL color space where saturation and lightness are constant. So we only need to vary the hue (from green to red) based on a portion of the total hue range. We then convert those values to use UIColor's HSB initializer.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue

**Even Simpler:**

If you don't need to work in the HSL color space, this can be further simplified by directly setting the saturation and brightness values.

```
@objc func sliderValueDidChange(sender: UISlider) {
    let sliderPercentage = sender.value / sender.maximumValue
    let invertedPercentage = 1 - sliderPercentage
    let hue = CGFloat(invertedPercentage * 120 / 360)

    let trackColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 0.95, brightness: 0.87, alpha: 1)
    brokeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = trackColor
}
```

Comment: Animated GIF is  a nice touch :-)